# <esb-home>/repository/conf/axis2.xml vs <esb-home>/samples/axis2Server/repository/conf/axis2.xml

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I want to know what is the basic difference between these to files - in terms of both functionality and usage.

I am trying to run this [sample](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/transport_samples.html#Sample256) And I cannot run it I have no idea where I am making a mistake. This is the error I am getting.

> [2012-06-15 14:42:03,557] ERROR - AxisEngine The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is  and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is  and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.processMail(MailTransportListener.java:515)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.access$000(MailTransportListener.java:61)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener$MailProcessor.run(MailTransportListener.java:331)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.processMail(MailTransportListener.java:295)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.checkMail(MailTransportListener.java:199)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.poll(MailTransportListener.java:80)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.poll(MailTransportListener.java:61)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2.xml is the main axis2 configuration used by the carbon servers..

ESB_HOME/samples/axis2serevr/repository/conf/axis2.xml is the axis2 configuration used by the sample axis2 server which is available in the wso2ESB distribution..
The error says your operation is not found at the service..Did you deploy the simplestockquote service at your sample axis2server as mentioned in the samples setup guide?